# How can I show a live progress bar and execute other code at the same time in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, terminal

I'm making a little game that runs in the terminal and I'm writing it using ruby. I want the user to type the correct text before the time runs out, and while I can do this using `Timeout`, I also want to provide a visual progress bar during the question.  I'm pretty sure I need to use either `Thread` or `Process` but these are totally new to me.  Here's an example of what I tried.

```
def what_is_capitol
  Thread.new do 
    progress = ProgressBar.create
    100.times{ progress.increment; sleep 0.1 }
  end
  puts "What is the capitol of New York"
  begin   
    Timeout::timeout(10) {
      @answer = gets.chomp
      if @answer == "Albany"
        puts "Correct"
        return @game_status = true
      else
        puts "No, try again"
        what_is_capitol
      end
    }
  rescue
    @game_status = false
  end
end
```

Here, the `Thread.new` block executes before moving on to the question. How can I modify this so that I have a progress bar that runs immediately, then allows the user to enter the answer while the progress bar is running?

Comment: Getting the progress bar to move while asking for input might be a problem. From which library are you getting `ProgressBar` and `Timeout`?

Comment: `ProgressBar` is from this gem: https://github.com/jfelchner/ruby-progressbar. `Timeout` is from the Std-Lib module (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html)